# How can I add a checkbox on a product page in WooCommerce that adds a fixed fee when checked?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, conditional-statements

Here is the trouble I'm having. I'm creating a custom kitchen cabinet doors and drawers website with Woocommerce. There are a lot of variations going into the project that alters the price (Wood type, thickness etc.) per square foot. The customer also has to provide credentials (L x W) to calculate the total cost of the product. We found that using the Measurement Price Calculator plugin works the best as it also calculated the weight of the product which can be used for shipping.

However, we want to add an option (preferably checkbox) that adds a fixed fee to the product if checked. Using WooCommerce itself and having "Boring" as a variable attribute doesn't work because adding a charge here will only add to the price per square foot and will not be fixed regardless of the dimensions.

I'm not a master at PHP and have only found ways to add a surcharge in the checkout but I need the fee to be conditional to the checkbox being checked and be replicated based on quantity. If there are any functions or hooks that you think could help me please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a part of WooCommerce that was separated and turned into a paid plugin called [WooCommerce Product Add-Ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/).

Koda